# Adding a hover effect when item is just below the top of the screen

Tags: jquery

I have a list of elements and I'm trying to add a class to each one of them when they are at the top of the viewable screen area, say 200px from the top.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$(".grid-item").each(function() {
            var viewableOffset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if ( viewableOffset < 200 ) {
                $Scripts(this).addClass("grid-item-hovered");
      }
});
```

However it doesn't seem to be doing what I expect. In fact it seems to be doing nothing.

The jQuery above along with a stripped down version of my html and css is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/1t92vcym/6/

The background of the .grid-item at the top of the viewport should be turning green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$Scripts` is not a correct identifier of jQuery unless you have defined it.
2. Also you are missing the `scroll` event handler of window.

So, make some changes of your script:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() { // added
  $(".grid-item").each(function() {
        var viewableOffset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
        if ( viewableOffset < 200 ) {
          $(this).addClass("grid-item-hovered"); // revised
        }
  });
}); // added
```

Comment: That was it, thank you can't believe I overlooked something so trivial. I did have $Scripts defined but I meant to remove them all for the purpose of sharing it here, obviously missed that one sorry.

I modified your solution slightly to remove the class when the user scrolls back up, the code can be found here in case it's of use to anyone finding this answer in future.

https://jsfiddle.net/1t92vcym/17/